# delete a property of object using Vue attribute given by DOM

Tags: javascript, object, dom, vuejs2

I am using v-for with `node` variable that runs on all properties in *TreeObject* object.
How can I delete one of the properties having only this *node* in my hand? (assume the function **can't access** *TreeObject*)

HTML:

```html
<div v-for="node in TreeObject">
  <div>{{ node.name }}</div>
  <button @click="Delete(node)">delete</button>
</div>
```

Script:

```js
[...]
methods: {
  Delete(node) {
    // somehow I want to delete node from TreeObject
  }
}
```

Comment: Confused to why `Delete` doesn't have access to `TreeObject`

Comment: Well, the situation is more complicated than what I show here..
In fact, I render the DOM recursively according to the tree (a nested object).
In this case, each DOM element doesn't know anything about other elements (unless these are its children)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `TreeObject` is an Array of Objects and their only defining identifier is their `name` property - use that property to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) `out` the node-in-question.

If `TreeObject` is a `prop` on the Component (read-only) - Make a copy of `TreeObject` and set it to a `data` property of say `DynamicTreeObject` and use that property in the `template`
Or use a `callback` prop like `onDelete` to pass the node-in-question out to the parent Component that has access to the original `TreeObject` and make your deletions there, then the data will trickle down to your child Component.

```js
Delete (node) {
  this.TreeObject = this.TreeObject.filter(n => n.name !== node.name)
}
```

Comment: Callback function \ emit can good here and I guess will be my last hope.
The problem with it is that the root will need to find the one who emitted which results search on all the tree.
I was hoping there might be a better way, considering the fact that I have `node` already

Comment: you could run a find on the document for that specific node and `removeChild` that it. you'd then have to somehow re-trigger the query for the `TreeObject` maybe and then populate downwards back to your Component. to be honest - the issue is very strange and seems a massive anti-pattern.